# How to add image to RadTreeNode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, .net-4.0

Hey,
I'm working on building a treeview dynamically based onClicked event for a menu item.

```
function onClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
 var treeView = $find("<%= RadTreeView1.ClientID %>");
 var selectedNode = treeView.get_selectedNode();        
 var node = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode(); 
 var parent = treeView.get_selectedNode();
 node.Image= "~/Images/Folder-Add-icon.png";
 parent.get_nodes().add(node);
 treeView.commitChanges();
}
```

But, the problem is I'm not getting the image next to the node when I try to add it, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you accidentally skipped to execute the trackChanges() method of the treeview before building the new node, i.e.

```
    function onClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
     var treeView = $find("<%= RadTreeView1.ClientID %>");
     treeView.trackChanges();       
     var node = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode(); 
     var parent = treeView.get_selectedNode();
     node.Image= "~/Images/Folder-Add-icon.png";
     parent.get_nodes().add(node);
     treeView.commitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result "no image" .. i think this assignment is wrong, maybe there's a "set" method .. but i can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the set_imageUrl() method:

```
var node = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode();
node.set_imageUrl("/Images/Folder-Add-icon.png");
```

Here are some terrific examples of the Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode object's methods:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreenode.html